# yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml", line 15, column 14

Tags: node.js, docker

im trying to run the code im geeting the error like

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 15, column 14
```

YAML file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
    restart: always
      service:
        build: .
          environment:
            -MY_MESSAGE=load1
          labels:
            -'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:load.test'
            -'traefik.backend=load'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of indentation in docker-compose file. Also, you need to follow the [syntax of version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) like for environment variable and label.

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
    restart: always


  service:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MY_MESSAGE= "load1"
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule:"Host:load.test"
      - traefik.backend:"load"
```